# Does a coal plant "kill more in a few weeks than nuclear has ever killed"?

Tags: mortality, radiation, nuclear-energy, power-generation, pollution

Director Oliver Stone and [Prof. Joshua Goldstein](http://www.joshuagoldstein.com) have created a [film named "Nuclear Now"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt21376908/), arguing in favor of installing more (modern) nuclear power plants to combat climate change and generally. In [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6GGJWelpBA) on the Hill's 'Rising TV', Prof. Goldstein makes the following claim around 19:10 :

> ... you know, a coal plant, on a good day when it's operating normally, kills more people in a few weeks than nuclear power has ever killed...

now, naturally, one has to quantify what size/output coal plant and how many weeks are a few weeks, but - how true is this statement?

---

<sub>Note: Regardless of whether this is true or not, that is a manipulative statement in at least several ways: The debate is not coal-vs-nuclear but more nuclear-vs-renewables-plus-storage; coal technology can likely be improved so that the pollution effects are reduced to almost zero, just like nuclear technology can likely be improved to what its proponents argue for; and finally and most importantly - the counting of deaths should be of estimated deaths, not just the actual deaths so far: If a nuclear plant has a X% change of emitting large amounts of radioactive material into the ocean or a wide populated area, so as to cause N deaths, but it has never actually done so, it's true that it has killed nobody, but its expected kills are N * X% (simplistically).</sub>

Comment: It seems to be rather difficult to put a reliable number on deaths caused by nuclear power, for Chernobyl alone there are widely diverging numbers and the official ones really only cover people that died directly in the accident while for coal the numbers are usually based on overall impact of pollution.

Comment: There is some of that addressed in https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/do-coal-plants-release-more-radiation-than-nuclear-power-plants?rq=1 from quite a ways back. Pollution from a standard coal plant would have to kill more than maybe 30 people (the semi-official Chernobyl death toll) a month for this to be true.

Comment: Prof. Goldstein makes other unsubstantiated claims elsewhere : _The only fatal nuclear accident was Chernobyl, which might have led to several thousand eventual cancer deaths – but that’s roughly the number killed by coal worldwide on an average day._ [Sustainability Times](https://www.sustainability-times.com/expert/joshua-goldstein-nuclear-power-for-a-bright-future/). Up-voted +1.

Comment: According to an [NGOs report titled Europe’s dark cloud: How coal-burning countries make their neighbours sick](https://www.wwf.eu/?272916/Europes-dark-cloud-How-coal-burning-countries-make-their-neighbours-sick) emissions of coal-fired power stations were responsible for over 22,900 premature deaths in 2013.

Comment: @MadScientist: That's certain. Effects of nuclear explosion are very diffuse over time unless you were exposed to a very high dose.

Comment: The report titled ["The Health Effects of Chernobyl"](https://www.sortirdunucleaire.org/IMG/pdf/ippnw-2006-the_health_effects_of_chernobyl-20_years_after_the_reactor_catastrophe.pdf) by International Physicians for the Prevention of Nuclear War (IPPNW) communicates on  a number between 10,000 and 25,000 additional fatalities due to cancer and leukaemia.

Comment: @Graffito please expand that to an answer. Why is it a comment?

Comment: @WeatherVane: using the words of *MadScientist*, it's impossible to put a reliable number on deaths caused by coal plants, specially if you consider the climatic effects. That's why I can't answer to the question.

Comment: @NigelJ “The *only* fatal nuclear accident...” I think that going too technical won't change the overall data. True, there had been fatalities from multiple criticality accidents (e.g., SL-1), but the number is perhaps under 20 (I undercount 8), negligible compared to Chernobyl, which may be, from trustworthy sources, in the 3,000‒30,000 range. The geometric mean is a good estimator for an order-of-mag discrepancy. 3MI and Fukushima had no fatalities. The meaning of your concern hinges on that of  “unsubstantiated”—did _he_ not provide sources, or his numbers can be _countered_ by sources.

Comment: @Graffito Right, exact estimate has a wide error bar, but there's a good technique, used by MichaelK in the answer: put the lower bound on coal, compare with the upper bound for nuclear. This works as an answer to a yes/no question without any statistical concerns.

Comment: When you shut down a coal plant, it's done.  When you shut down a nuclear plant, it could continue to kill people for tens of thousands of years.  Hardly a fair comparison.

Comment: As a side note, fatalities are only one category of the negative effects of a nuclear disaster.  The other effects (loss of land, loss of infrastructure, loss of jobs, loss of trade, loss of peoples' health) might actually be more impactful than the direct fatalities, in the long run.

Comment: @MarkRansom we already used enough fossil fuels that it probably won't be possible to kill people for tens of thousands of years anyway...

Comment: Your question was interesting. And then you added the note, complaining about inaccuracies by starting with two unsourced and wrong statements. "The debate is not coal-vs-nuclear but more nuclear-vs-renewables-plus-storage; coal technology can be improved so that the pollution effects are reduced to almost zero". Well, no.

Comment: @EricDuminil: Added 'likely' to the claims in the comment. Also - sure they can - they could just collect the particulate matter from the chimneys/furnace exhausts instead of spewing it into the air. Of course, that would reduce energy efficiency and increase costs.

Comment: @einpoklum did you just ignore the CO2 emissions of a coal power plant?

Comment: @EricDuminil: I suppose that I have.... are there CO2 inhalation fatalities around coal power plants?

Comment: @einpoklum: Since we're talking about coal and nuclear power plants in general: It's perfectly fine to take into account the global impact of every plant, and divide by the number of plants. You'll probably won't be able to pinpoint a specific coal power plant for any death related to climate change. It doesn't mean that CO2 is harmless, and should be ignored, though. Especially not for coal power plants. Anyway, your biased note pretty much disqualified you for any discussion about energy policies.

Comment: I don't understand why everyone is focusing only on whether the number attributed to nuclear power is too low, and not to where the number for coal comes from. Are we actually talking about deaths directly attributable to nearby coal power plants here, or is this some kind of "excess death" total based on extrapolations of climate change? The whole comparison is meaningless unless some definition is given for what causes we're considering.

Comment: @IMSoP: If you ask me, climate change deaths can't count, since the quote talked about deaths from a few weeks of operation. Also, it's too indirect - it's not exposure to CO_2 produced by the plant, but an overall balance of CO_2 capture and release, and even that doesn't kill anyone, but effects social and physical changes, which in turn will likely result in deaths. But your point is well taken.

Comment: I would argue that is unanswerable because "pollution kills" is an imprecise statement. Air pollution shortens lives, just like low-level radiation, if we're talking about just operation and accidents that affect more than the workers (and not mining etc.) For pollution it makes more sense to count years of life lost than some arbitrary threshold where you count someone as killed by air pollution (or not), someone killed by cancer as possibly killed by radiation (or not), etc. The answers below all have this problem (including the fairly upvoted by deleted one).

Comment: Uranium miners definitely have higher than average risk of death, even in developed countries. https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/pgms/worknotify/uranium.html#:~:text=We%20found%20strong%20evidence%20for,radon%20daughters%20in%20the%20mines. So do we count all Uranium mine workers as being killed by nuclear power?

Comment: To say nothing of past conditions in the USSR, where e.g. one (US) paper says 75% of said miners died of lung cancer! https://ehss.energy.gov/ohre/roadmap/achre/chap12_2.html

Comment: Another paper puts the death rate in the USSR uranium mining camps at nearly 100% https://hal.science/hal-01962079/file/Uranium%20mines%20working%20paper.pdf

Comment: The same is basically true about the green tech. All the children digging cobalt in the DRC etc. https://www.cbsnews.com/news/the-toll-of-the-cobalt-mining-industry-congo/

Comment: @Fizz "The green tech" all needs Cobalt?

Comment: No, but storage does. Non-renewables (fossil, nuclear) aren't affected by the storage issue as much (although hardly anyone proposes to have personal cars directly powered by nuclear reactors).

Comment: @Fizz: I know that mobile phones use some Cobalt, but - large batteries? Some of them use Lithium, but alternatives to that are in the works. I don't know about Cobalt. Link?

Comment: https://www.cobaltinstitute.org/essential-cobalt-2/powering-the-green-economy/batteries-electric-vehicles/#:~:text=Cobalt%20is%20an%20essential%20part,containing%2010%2D20%25%20cobalt. The DOE is pushing for low-cobalt batteries, but these are mostly research for now https://www.energy.gov/eere/vehicles/articles/reducing-reliance-cobalt-lithium-ion-batteries "Cobalt is considered the highest material supply chain risk for electric vehicles (EVs) in the short and medium term. "

Comment: @Fizz: Well, I wouldn't call consumer electronics and EVs green tech... but yeah, it seems Lithium batteries require Cobalt as well. Luckily, Lithium+Cobalt will soon [start disappearing in favor of Sodium](https://www.cnbc.com/2023/05/10/sodium-ion-batteries-shaping-up-to-be-big-technology-breakthrough.html) and possibly other emerging technologies.

Comment: Also, according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qntd7i4Jk3M) (i.e. according to a random guy on YouTube), there is already transition from Nickel-Manganese-Cobalt to [Lithium-Iron-Phosphate](https://www.pnnl.gov/lithium-ion-battery-lfp-and-nmc) for Lithium batteries.

Comment: Curious is to whether claims range as far as Black Lung death tolls vs uranium mining effects.

Comment: @Fizz Could you please re-check your sources? I'm having a hard time finding references to USSR miner death rates in [this article you linked](https://ehss.energy.gov/ohre/roadmap/achre/chap12_2.html) (it seems to deal solely with USA labour safety legislation). And [this one](https://hal.science/hal-01962079/file/Uranium%20mines%20working%20paper.pdf) is either an art performance or a weird attempt at trolling, because it's clearly not even trying to be credible scientific research.

Comment: @IMSoP Doesn't need to be just a nearby coal plant.  I would presume coal deaths include things like deaths due to the mercury they put in the food chain.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Could be, but there was no discussion of that in the question or any of the answers when I wrote that comment. If you can find good sources using a clear definition for how many deaths should be attributed to that, *and equivalent factors caused by nuclear*, then by all means post an answer.

Comment: @IMSoP I would assume the comparison was coal deaths/number of plants/few weeks per year vs nuclear deaths/number of plants*lifespan of a nuke plant.

Comment: @LorenPechtel That's not the part of the formula that I was questioning. I was questioning what the "coal deaths" figure includes. It's not like thousands of people are accidentally eating coal, and immediately dying of acute poisoning; anyone claiming a figure has to first decide what effects/events are attributable to coal power, and then estimate how many deaths happened primarily due to those effects/events. What they divide and multiply those figures by is irrelevant until we've pinned down what the figures actually include.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The claim as made in the original quote is fairly easy to debunk with sources from the comments because it compares deaths due to all nuclear power over all time with deaths of a single coal power plant over a few weeks.

First nuclear from user Graffito: 'a report titled ["The Health Effects of Chernobyl"](https://www.sortirdunucleaire.org/IMG/pdf/ippnw-2006-the_health_effects_of_chernobyl-20_years_after_the_reactor_catastrophe.pdf) by International Physicians for the Prevention of Nuclear War (IPPNW) communicates on a number between 10,000 and 25,000 additional fatalities due to cancer and leukaemia.' We will use the 10,000 as a low estimate for total nuclear deaths.

Now consider the country as Poland as a randomly chosen example. There are 50 coal power plants in [Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_power_stations_in_Poland) unless I miscounted the list. Hence according to this claim coal power plants in Poland would have to kill more than 500,000 people every few weeks. [Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Poland)  has around 38 million inhabitants and a death rateof 13.6 per 1000 per year which gives approximately 516,000 deaths per year in total from all causes combined. So whatever the number of deaths due to coal power plants in Poland actually is, it is certainly several orders of magnitude smaller than claimed.

One could argue that Polish power plants kill people in other countries but other countries have coal power plants as well so this wouldn't change the answer that dramatically. The original claim is so way over the top wrong that no accurate accounting of deaths due to coal power plants is needed to debunk it.

Comment: What's your reference for less than 1% Polish people dying annually from deaths attributable to coal power plants?

Comment: @einpoklum Googled the numbers, adjusted them slightly and added a reference.

Comment: Straight and to the point without a lot of sophistry.

Comment: I don't think using single country provides good evidence either way.

Comment: @JoeW It does in this case because the orginal claim is so far out that the difference between countries is irrelevant in comparison. You are welcome to write an answer using the entire world. If you do the same computation worldwide you will also find that the number of claimed death due to coal power is bigger than the total number of death to all causes.

Comment: I posted that comment because that isn't what I got from your answer.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noticing that the IPPNW report you are linking to is not a reviewed publication and disagrees significantly with estimated death tolls published by WHO. The report even mentions this in the introduction and claims that WHO has manipulated their own data. I am not able to judge either the numbers in this report, nor the numbers from WHO, but the report sounds slightly fishy.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Note that the [WHO report](https://www.who.int/news-room/detail/05-09-2005-chernobyl-the-true-scale-of-the-accident) estimates 4,000 deaths due to Chernobyl. Replacing the estimate of 10,000 with 4,000 does not change the conclusion of this answer - for the claim to be true, there would have to be more deaths due to coal plants in Poland per year than total deaths in Poland per year.